# Can't read/find node in signed XML file using c#

Tags: c#, xml

```
String fileName = "signed_file.xml";
      String filecopy = "signed_file_copy.xml";


       File.Copy(fileName, filecopy, true);

        /* Remove the digital signature */
        XDocument doc1 = XDocument.Load(filecopy);

        XElement signElement = doc1.Descendants("Signature").FirstOrDefault<XElement>();

        signElement.Remove();
```

signElement is null, even though signed_file_copy.xml has the 
Signature tag in it. Need help to understand what is going on.

The Signature tag structure in XML looks like below

```
<Config>
<Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
 <SignedInfo>
  <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" /> 
  <SignatureMethod Algorithm=xxxxxxxxx /> 
  <Reference URI="">
  <Transforms>
  <Transform Algorithm=zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz /> 
  </Transforms>
  <DigestMethod Algorithm=yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy /> 
  <DigestValue> xxxxxxxxxxx </DigestValue> 
  </Reference>
  </SignedInfo>
  <SignatureValue>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</SignatureValue> 
</Signature>
</Config>
```

Comment: Does the XML file use namespaces?

Comment: Show the xml or an example of it

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
XElement signElement =
    doc1
        .Descendants(
            XName.Get("Signature", "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"))
        .FirstOrDefault();
```

Your `Signature` tag has a namespace, so you must use it to find the element.